# Azure VPN Client with Azure Certificate Authentication connecting to Virtual Network Gateway

Tags: vpn, azure, vpn-client, point-to-site-vpn

Trying to configure the Azure VPN Client to connect to Virtual Network Gateway using Azure Certificate Authentication.

The Azure VPN Client asks for Server Validation config info for "Certificate Information" and "Server Secret".

Are these relevant for Azure Certificate Authentication, and if so, where do I find these parameters on my Virtual Network Gateway that has been configured without a Radius Server??

[Azure Client VPN Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxCHi.jpg)